# Test configuration error configurating SSH servers to connect to server belongs to a bastion host

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I wanted to deploy a nodejs build to a server that belongs to a bastion host.
When configurating the SSH servers on jenkins, I got the next error when testing the configuration:

> jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect
> and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for
> config [bastion-host]. Message [java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> refused (Connection refused)]]

below the screenshot of the configuration:
[[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its because of Jsch plugin update and issues with the jar. temporary solution explained here, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77761205/5385130