# Error: jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection

Tags: jenkins, devops

error: jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [WebService]. Message [Auth fail]]

img1: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htoFm.png
img1: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ9Bz.png

Answer (score 0):

this is because of jsch plugin update in Jenkins. try lowering your jsch plugin with its other dependencies or try copying both the old and New Jars together in your **"%JENKINS_HOME%\plugins\jsch\WEB-INF\lib"** folder. so both old and new are Available.

e.g see the below picture.
[image]